# google cloud: need python 3.6 and is 3.6 in ssh but still 3.5 in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-python

I need to use python 3.6 for a project and in the ssh when I typed

```
python3 --version
#Python 3.6.3
```

but in the jupyter notebook i opened, it is still

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516]
```

**How can I change it to python 3.6?**

I can see that when I opened jupyter notebook, python3.6 is in the directory:
[image]
I know there is a similar question in stackoverflow but is not answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training my_job \
    --module-name trainer.task \
    --job-dir gs://my/training/job/directory \
    --package-path /path/to/my/project/trainer \
    --region us-central1 \
    --runtime-version 2.1 \
    --python-version 3.6
```

However, looking at the [runtime version list](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/runtime-version-list) and the [Setting Python version](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/versioning#set-python-version-training) pages, I only see mentioned python 3.5 and python 3.7.

Could you maybe try the packages you are having issues with in 3.5 in a 3.7 environment:

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training my_job \
    --module-name trainer.task \
    --job-dir gs://my/training/job/directory \
    --package-path /path/to/my/project/trainer \
    --region us-central1 \
    --runtime-version 2.1 \
    --python-version 3.7
```